# Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code with Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)?

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-code, tfvc

I am building AngularJS/TypeScript app using Visual Studio Code in my Mac and it is a great experience so far. The group of people I work with are using Team Services as source control instead of Git. Is there an extension or plugin available for Visual Studio Code which enables me to use Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: I suppose you mean TFVC as the source control system.

Comment: TFVC is now supported by VS Code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385842/7862382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not it's not possible to use TFVC as your source control system directly. But you have a few options.

1. In Visual Studio Team Services (the new name of Visual Studio Online/TFS Online), you can have both a TFVC and a git repository in the same Team project.
2. You could use [git tf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474) to use git on your end, yet push you changes to a TFVC repository. There are limitations (as the two systems are not the same of course).

Comment: Did not think about it.

Comment: Jesse, you forgot to mention Team Explorer Everywhere as an option to operate on TFVC from any Java supported platform.

Comment: That doesn't feel like integration into vs code, does it :)