# Visual Studio Code w/ Team Foundation Version Control

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

Can I use Visual Studio Code against VSTS using Team Foundation Version Control?

I see that VS Code supports Git but I don't see TF version control anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCODE and TFVC how to connect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163727/vscode-and-tfvc-how-to-connect)

Comment: TFVC is now supported by VS Code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385842/7862382

Answer (score 0):

VS Code only supports Git version control by default. But you can try [vscode-tfs](https://github.com/ivangabriele/vscode-tfs) extension if you want to integrate VS Code with TFVC.