# Introducing Angular2 into an existing Microsoft environment with TFS and VS2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

It would seem that the culmination of Google's Angular and Microsoft's Typescript in Angular2 would provide the perfect platform for an existing Microsoft shop who plans to move from a desktop application to a web application. In a sense it is, Typescript is an easy transition from C# and the statefulness of Angular transfers well for those used to desktop applications.  However I have been struggling with something I never expected. Our IDE has always been Visual Studio, and we all own a 2015 license.  We also own the licensing for TFS 2015.  However it would seem that using Angular2 in VS2015 is not ideal.  I have spent many hours trying to get it setup properly, but it is at best challenging.  To be fair I did get it working, but the experience with Visual Studio Code is far superior and less prone to issues.  It also seems very obvious that Microsoft/the powers that be would prefer you use Visual Studio Code instead of VS2015 considering that nearly every tutorial uses Code. There is even an afterthought [Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html) article for VS2015 in the Angular2 docs that doesn't seem to work at all for me. That seems to further cement it's lack of support. I guess I was expecting this problem to be resolved with a project template or something of the sort shortly after the Angular2 final release, but 2.1.0 is released and no such luck.  In fact if you open Bower in VS2015 and try to install Angular2 it crashes Visual Studio. If we decide to use VS Code then there is no native support for TFS unless you are hosting a Git repository.  All of our code is currently in TFVC and we would obviously prefer to have our new Angular2 project in the same.

I realize I've rambled a bit, but here are my points. Are there plans to make the VS2015/Angular2 environment friendly in the future?  Is there a simple solution for VS2015/TFS2015 license owning customers that I'm missing?  Is there a simple solution for TFVC and VSCode (pretty sure I know the answer here). Can someone explain why these issues aren't being addressed? It would seem there must be a number of developers in this same boat.

UPDATE:

This article surprised me somewhat. Might just be my answer though:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc

Comment: These are questions for microsoft forums / support.

Comment: Are you using a classic ASP.NET project or an ASP.NET Core project? I remember having more luck with the latter when trying out Angular2.

Comment: It was a core project. I've since switched to VS Code and angular CLI

Comment: TFVC is now supported by VS Code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385842/7862382